# Can't open matlab file

Tags: matlab

I have a ".mat" file supposedly containing a [30720000x4 double] matrix (values from accelerometers). When I try to open this file with "Import data" in Matlab I get the following error:

```
Error using load
Can't read file F:\vibration_exp_2\GR_UB50n\bearing1\GR_UB50n_1_2.mat.

Error using load
Unknown text on line number 1 of ASCII file
F:\vibration_exp_2\GR_UB50n\bearing1\GR_UB50n_1_2.mat
"MATLAB".

Error in uiimport/runImportdata (line 456)
                    datastruct = load('-ascii', fileAbsolutePath);

Error in uiimport/gatherFilePreviewData (line 424)
        [datastruct, textDelimiter, headerLines]= runImportdata(fileAbsolutePath,
        type);

Error in uiimport (line 240)
[ctorPreviewText, ctorHeaderLines, ctorDelim] = ...
```

The filesize is 921MB which is the same as my other files that do open. I also tried opening the file using python, but no success. Any suggestions?  I use MATLAB R2013b .

---

**More info:**

How the file was create:

```
%% acquisition of vibration data
% input:
% sample rate in Hz (max. 51200 Hz, should be used as bearing 
% faults are high-frequent)
% time in seconds, stating the duration of the measurement 
% (e.g. 600 seconds = 10 minutes)
% filename for the file to be saved
%
% examples:
% data = DAQ(51200, 600, 'NF1_1.mat'); 
% data = DAQ(51200, 600, 'NF1_2.mat'); 
function data = DAQ(samplerate,time,filename) 

s = daq.createSession('ni'); % Creates the DAQ session
%%% Add the channels as accelerometer channels (meaning IEPE is turned on)
s.addAnalogInputChannel('cDAQ1Mod1','ai0','Accelerometer'); 
s.addAnalogInputChannel('cDAQ1Mod1','ai1','Accelerometer'); 
s.addAnalogInputChannel('cDAQ1Mod1','ai2','Accelerometer'); 
s.addAnalogInputChannel('cDAQ1Mod1','ai3','Accelerometer'); 
%s.addAnalogInputChannel('cDAQ1Mod2','ai0','Accelerometer'); 

s.Rate = samplerate;
s.NumberOfScans = samplerate*time; 
%%% Defining the Sensitivities in V/g
s.Channels(1).Sensitivity = 0.09478; %31965, top outer
s.Channels(2).Sensitivity = 0.09531; %31966, back outer
s.Channels(3).Sensitivity = 0.09275; %31964, top inner
s.Channels(4).Sensitivity = 0.09363; %31963, back inner

data = s.startForeground(); %Acquiring the data

save(filename, 'data');
```

---

**More info:**

When I open the file using a simple text editor I can see a lot of characters that do not make sense​ but also the first line:

> MATLAB 5.0 MAT-FILE, Platform: PCWIN64, Created on: Thu Apr 30
>   16:29:07 2015

---

**More info:**
The file itself: https://www.dropbox.com/s/r7mavil79j47xa2/GR_UB50n_1_2.mat?dl=0
It is 921MB.

---

**EDIT:**

**How can I recover my data?**

I've tried [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/98890-how-do-i-recover-data-from-a-corrupt-mat-file), but got memory errors.
I've also tried [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/42274-loadfixnames-loads-a-mat-file--fixing-invalid-names), but it did not work.

Comment: `importdata`!=`load`. For .mat files you should use `load` separately. Apparently `importdata` uses this under the hood.

Comment: Well, i tried load also, then I get a simple error saying it can't open the file. (No further info given)

Comment: Where did this file come from? Is it actually a `*.mat` file?

Comment: I'll add the script wherein the file is created to the question. It is a .mat file, I have many other files created by the same script that do work. I think the file is somehow corrupt, nevertheless, the filesize is ok, so I'm looking for a way to recover my data.

Comment: Is the MATLAB version used to save these files the same as the one you're using? Is this the only file with the issue? What happens with `load(filename, '-mat')`?

Comment: MATLAB R2013b or MATLAB R2014a, I also tried both to open the file. At the moment it is the only file with this issue, I am checking other files too at the moment.

Comment: Were you ever able to open this file or has it always been broken? If it worked before and you backup your data (as I'm sure you do) then try one of your backups.

Comment: I find it strange that the file indicates that is a "MATLAB 5.0 MAT-FILE". The `save` command supposedly [defaults to version 7.3](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html#input_argument_version) for Matlab versions R2006b and later. Did you change something in the preferences?

Comment: @horchler that refers to the file format version, not the MATLAB version. the latest fileformat version is 'level 5' as of r2015b

Comment: Here is the file format specification, you could try to parse the file yourself and see how far you can go... https://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/matfile_format.pdf

Comment: @gregswiss: I was referring to the versions [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html#input_argument_version). I assumed that there would be some correlation with the header, but I guess not. Thanks.

Comment: In Octave 3.6.4 on Windows 7, I get this message when I open the file `error: memory exhausted or requested size too large for range of Octave's index type -- trying to return to prompt`. It does not specify a file format issue. Could it be that MatLab has the same problem -- that it just cannot handle the size?

Comment: You might have success opening your mat file using [CSMatIO](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/16319-csmatio--mat-file-i-o-api-for-net-2-0) in c#.

Answer (score 4):

I fear I can't add many good news to what you know already, but it hasn't been mentioned yet.

The reason the .mat-file can't be load is due to the data beeing corrupted. What makes it 'unrecoverable' is the way it is stored internally. The exact format is specified in the [MAT-File Format Documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/matfile_format.pdf). So I decided to manually construct a simple reader to specifically read your .mat file.

It makes sense, that the `splitmat.m` can't recover anything, as it will basicly split the data into chunks, one stored variable per chunk, however in this case there is only 1 variable stored and thus only one chunk, which happens to be the corrupted one.

In this case, the data is stored as a `miCOMPRESSED`, which is a normal matlab array compressed using gzip. (Which, as a side note, doesn't seem like a good fit for 'random' vibration data.) This might explain previous comments about the smaller file size then the full data, as the filesize matches exatly with the internally stored value.

I extracted the compressed archive and tried to uncompress it in a variety of ways. Basicly it is a '.gz' without the header, that can be appended manually. Unfortunatly there seems to be a corrupted block near the start of the dataset. I am by no means an expert on gzip, but as far as I know the dictionary (or decryption key) is stored dynamicly which makes all data useless from the point the block is corrupted. If you are really eager, there seems to be [a way to recover data](http://www.gzip.org/recover.txt) even behind the point where data is corrupted, but that method is massively timeconsuming. Also the only way to validate data of those sections is manual inspection, which in your case might proof very difficult.

Below is the code, that I used to extract the .gz-file, so if you want to give it a try, this might get you started. If you manage to decrypt the data, you can read it as described in the [MAT-File Format](http://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/matfile_format.pdf), 13f.

```
corrupted_file_id = fopen('corrupt.mat','r');
%% some header data
% can be skipped replacing this block with
% fread(id,132);

%header of .mat file
header_text = char(fread(corrupted_file_id,116,'char')');
subsystem_data_offset = fread(corrupted_file_id,8,'uint8');
version = fread(corrupted_file_id,1,'int16');
endian_indicator = char(fread(corrupted_file_id,2,'int8')');
data_type = fread(corrupted_file_id,4,'uint8'); 
%data_type is 15, so it is a compressed matlab array


%% save te content
data_size = fread(corrupted_file_id,1,'uint32');
gz_file_id = fopen('compressed_array.gz','w');
% first write a valid gzip head
fwrite(gz_file_id,hex2dec('1f8b080000000000'),'uint64',0,'b');

% then write the data sequentialy 
step = 1:1e3:data_size;% 1MB steps
for idx = step
fwrite(gz_file_id,fread(corrupted_file_id,1e3,'uint8'));
end
step = step(end):data_size;% 1B steps
for idx = step
    fwrite(gz_file_id,fread(corrupted_file_id,1,'uint8'));
end
fclose(gz_file_id);
fclose(corrupted_file_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer *literally* to the question, my suggestion would be to make sure first that the file is okay. This tool on File Exchange apparently knows how to diagnose corrupted .MAT files starting with version V5 (R8):

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6893-matcat-mat-file-corruption-analysis-tool

Comment: Well, I tried the tool and it says the file is corrupt.

Comment: @Ojtwist Can you confirm with the ones that provided the file that the data saving wasn't stopped by disk full, out of disk quota or power failure?

Comment: @Ojtwist You should check the MATLAB Central forums, they cover quite a lot of issues. For example: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/98890-how-do-i-recover-data-from-a-corrupt-mat-file

Comment: @Ojtwist But can you confirm that the file was generated successfully?

Comment: Supposedly yes. What I can say for sure is that the variable "data" inside the .mat file has the correct dimensions. Also, the file has the right size ( it should be around 920 MB, which it is). So it seems logical to me that some data should be recoverable ...

Answer (score 0):

The file's size (indices going out of range) seems to be a problem. `Octave`, which should read `.mat` files, gives the error

```
memory exhausted or requested size too large for range of Octave's index type
```

To find out what is wrong you may need to write a test program outside MatLab, where you have more control over memory management. Examples are [here](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/list-of-examples.html), including instructions on how to build them on your own platform. These stand-alone programs may not have the same memory issues. The program `matdgns.c` is specifically made to check `.mat` files for errors.

Comment: Interested to hear the reason for downvoting this. The `matdgns.c` program is designed for diagnosing `.MAT` files so it is topical, and trying `Octave` instead of `Python` to open `.MAT` files (as done by the OP) is a logical idea.